# Getting error while compiling objective-c in ubuntu

Tags: objective-c, ubuntu, gcc

I am trying to compile a simple hello world program written in objective c from ubuntu but I am getting an error as

> gcc: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-fobjc-nonfragile-abi’

To compile I am using the command

> gcc `gnustep-config --objc-flags` -lgnustep-base hello.m -o hello

Can you please help me out with this. I am not getting any solution in google too.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to compile gnustep code is with makefiles. It avoids all this faff with GCC:

make a file called GNUmakefile

Make the content:

```
include $(GNUSTEP_MAKEFILES)/common.make

TOOL_NAME=hello
hello_OBJC_FILES=hello.m

include $(GNUSTEP_MAKEFILES)/tool.make
```

just type:

```
make
```

to compile, the output is in the obj/ dir

I would give this a read
http://www.gnustep.it/nicola/Tutorials/WritingMakefiles/

Now a problem I always have is it can't find the gnustep makefiles.
The long term fix is to add it to path, the quick fix is every session, type:

```
export GNUSTEP_MAKEFILES=/usr/share/GNUstep/Makefiles
```

/usr/share/GNUstep/Makefiles is my gnustep makefile dir, YOURS MAY BE DIFFERENT! but I assume that this is the dir if you installed gnustep like this:

apt-get install gnustep gnustep-devel

it may be worth making sure you have the gnustep-devel package!

Good luck!